# DevExtreme datagrid with server side paging/sorting not working with filtering

Tags: angular, devextreme

The paging and sorting works as expected on the server side and is showing the data correctly, but when I click on on a column with the filter enabled is showing everything with (Blanks)

[image]

If the `loadOptions.group` has a value it means that the filter is requesting the unique values to shown in the drop down

I know that I either have to filter that on the client or on the server, but **what is the structure(type of object) that has to be returned in order to make the filtering show the unique values and how is it filled ?**

```js
getOrderDataStore(
    orderSearchRequest: OrderSearchRequest,
    failureAction: ActionCreator<string, FunctionWithParametersType<any, any>>,
    store: Store): CustomStore {
    return new CustomStore({
      load: (loadOptions) => {
        console.log({ loadOptions: loadOptions });
        orderSearchRequest.pageSize = loadOptions.take;
        orderSearchRequest.page = loadOptions.take === 0 ? 1 : Math.ceil(loadOptions.skip / loadOptions.take) + 1;

        if (loadOptions.group) {
          console.log("about to filter");
          let x: any[] = [];
          x.push({ id: 1, value: 'a' });
          x.push({ id: 2, value: 'b' });
          return x;

          /*
          states = [
            { id: 1, state: "Alabama", capital: "Montgomery" },
            { id: 2, state: "Alaska", capital: "Juneau" },
            { id: 3, state: "Arizona", capital: "Phoenix" },
            // ...
          ];
          
          return new ArrayStore({
            key: "id",
            data: x,
            // Other ArrayStore properties go here
          });
          */
        }
        else {
          return this.searchOrder(orderSearchRequest)
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => {
              console.log({ getOrderDataStore: response.result.orders })
              return {
                data: response.result.orders,
                totalCount: response.result.totalCount
              };
            })
            .catch(() => {
              store.dispatch(failureAction({ error: 'Data loading error' }))
              throw 'Data loading error'
            });
        }
      },
    });
  }
```

I have checked many stackoverflow questions and also devextreme support forums without any luck

One of the many places I have checked include:

- https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/DataGrid/WebAPIService/Angular/Light/
- https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/19_2/Guide/Widgets/DataGrid/Data_Binding/Custom_Sources/
- https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Guide/UI_Components/PivotGrid/Use_CustomStore/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My aproach above was wrong

This is the way is done, using the `dxo-header-filter` for the given column

```html
<dx-data-grid ... >
    <dxi-column ... [allowHeaderFiltering]="true">
        <dxo-header-filter
            [dataSource]="headerFilterData">
        </dxo-header-filter>
    </dxi-column>
</dx-data-grid>
```

```js
export class AppComponent {
    headerFilterData: any;
    constructor() {
        this.headerFilterData = [{
            text: "Zero",
            value: 0
        }, {
            text: "Less than $3000",
            value: ["SaleAmount", "<", 3000]
        }, {
            text: "More than $3000",
            value: ["SaleAmount", ">", 3000]
        }];
    }
}
```

Taken from : https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Guide/UI_Components/DataGrid/How_To/Customize_Header_Filter_Data_Source/

And this is how it looks

[image]